# GTFS get last stop on trip

Tags: mysql, sql, gtfs

Using a standard **GTFS** database, I'm trying to add the name of the last stop on a trip to my current query which returns the following:

```
| trip_id                         | service_id | departure_stop | departure_time | arrival_stop    | arrival_time | end_departure |
|---------------------------------|------------|----------------|----------------|-----------------|--------------|---------------|
| 15693832.T6.2-EPP-E-mjp-1.11.R  | T6_1       | Clifton Hill   | 04:56:00       | Flinders Street | 05:07:00     | 05:07:00      |
```

and so on.

My current query is:

```
select `t`.`trip_id`,
       `c`.`service_id`,
       `start_s`.`stop_name` as `departure_stop`,
       `start_st`.`departure_time`,
       `end_s`.`stop_name` as `arrival_stop`,
       `end_st`.`arrival_time`,
       `end_st`.`departure_time` as `end_departure`
from `trips` as `t`
    inner join `calendar` as `c` on `t`.`service_id` = `c`.`service_id`
    inner join `routes` as `r` on `t`.`route_id` = `r`.`route_id` 
    inner join `stop_times` as `start_st` on `t`.`trip_id` = `start_st`.`trip_id` 
    inner join `stops` as `start_s` on `start_st`.`stop_id` = `start_s`.`stop_id` 
    inner join `stop_times` as `end_st` on `t`.`trip_id` = `end_st`.`trip_id` 
    inner join `stops` as `end_s` on `end_st`.`stop_id` = `end_s`.`stop_id` 
where `start_st`.`departure_time` > '00:00:00' 
    and `start_st`.`departure_time` < '23:59:59' 
    and `start_s`.`stop_id` = 19974 
    and `end_s`.`stop_id` = 19854 
    and start_st.departure_time < end_st.arrival_time
order by arrival_time asc
```

I'm stuck trying to figure out how I can get the last stop in the `stop_times` table for the `trip_id` that my query returns for each row.

So in addition to what I have currently, I'd like to:

- get the last `stop_id` for that `trip_id` in the `stop_times` table
- get the `stop_name` from the `stops` table for the corresponding `stop_id`
- display it as the last column in my output as `last_stop`

---

**Update:**

I've tried selecting `s.stop_name` and adding the following inner join:

```
inner join (
    SELECT s.stop_name, trip_id
        FROM stop_times 
        INNER JOIN stops as s on `s`.`stop_id` = `stop_times`.`stop_id`
        ORDER BY stop_sequence DESC
) s on `t`.`trip_id` = `s`.`trip_id`
```

However, this adds extra rows for every single stop in trip, where I only want the last one and adding `LIMIT 1` returns no results.

Comment: try adding end_s.stop_id = max(end_st.stop_sequence)

Comment: where specifically would I add that?

Comment: in the where clause. What this does is ensure that the ending stop_id is the maximum value (e.g. the final stop).

Comment: Oh. But `end_s` is the destination stop chosen by the user, I want it to also show the last possible stop in the entire run/trip

Comment: Then add a third join. This also might work in the join you mention in your update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One caution, arrival and departure times may be later than midnight in the GTFS spec (hour value could be 24, 25, etc.)

```
select "t"."trip_id",
       "c"."service_id",
       "start_s"."stop_name" as "departure_stop",
       "start_st"."departure_time",
       "end_s"."stop_name" as "arrival_stop",
       "end_st"."arrival_time",
       "end_st"."departure_time" as "end_departure",
       "last_st"."arrival_time" as "last_arrival",
       "last_s"."stop_name" as "last_stop"
from "trips" as "t"
    inner join "calendar" as "c" on "t"."service_id" = "c"."service_id"
    inner join "routes" as "r" on "t"."route_id" = "r"."route_id" 
    inner join "stop_times" as "start_st" on "t"."trip_id" = "start_st"."trip_id" 
    inner join "stops" as "start_s" on "start_st"."stop_id" = "start_s"."stop_id" 
    inner join "stop_times" as "end_st" on "t"."trip_id" = "end_st"."trip_id" 
    inner join "stops" as "end_s" on "end_st"."stop_id" = "end_s"."stop_id" 
    inner join "stop_times" as "last_st" on "t"."trip_id" = "last_st"."trip_id" 
    inner join "stops" as "last_s" on "last_st"."stop_id" = "last_s"."stop_id" 
where "start_s"."stop_id" = '245' -- my data's stop id
    and "end_s"."stop_id" = '762' -- my data's stop id
    and "last_st"."stop_sequence" = (select max("stop_sequence") from "stop_times" where "t"."trip_id" = "trip_id")
    and start_st.departure_time < end_st.arrival_time
order by arrival_time asc
```